# How to clear p:autoComplete values on page refresh or click back on browser in JSF using PrimeFaces?

Tags: jsf, primefaces, autocomplete

using p:autoComplete to display city name and test name. Here i select one city name and/or test name Then refresh page Still displayed selected values and also after search goes to another page and then clicked on Back arrow on browser values are not clear.
Here we are using `<p:autoComplete>` to display dropdown values. Here is my code.

I tried with jQuery.

```
<script>
    $(function () {
        $("#homePageForm").attr("autocomplete", "off");
    });
</script>
```

But it is not working.

```
<h:form id="homePageForm" styleClass="serform">
    <p:panel id="validate_home" >
        <div class="serbox subsel mydropbox">
            <p:autoComplete dropdown="true"
                            required="true"
                            requiredMessage="Testname required"
                            id="testDD"
                            forceSelection="true"
                            maxlength="6"
                            cache="true"
                            update="testMsg"
                            queryDelay="100"
                            value="#{searchController.testName}"
                            completeMethod="#{searchController.completeTest}">
            </p:autoComplete>

            <p:message for="testDD" id="testMsg" />
            <p:watermark for="testDD" value="Search TestName" id="testWatermark" />
        </div>

        <div class="serbox subsel mydropbox">
            <p:autoComplete dropdown="true"
                            required="true"
                            requiredMessage="City Name required"
                            id="cityDD"
                            forceSelection="true"
                            maxlength="6"
                            cache="true"
                            queryDelay="100"
                            value="#{searchController.city}"
                            completeMethod="#{searchController.completeCity}">

                <p:ajax event="itemSelect"
                        listener="#{searchController.onItemSelect}"
                        update="localityDD" />
            </p:autoComplete>
            <p:message for="cityDD" />
            <p:watermark for="cityDD" value="Search City" id="cityWatermark" />
        </div>

        <div class="serbox subsel mydropbox">
            <p:autoComplete dropdown="true"
                            required="false"
                            id="localityDD"
                            requiredMessage="Locality required"
                            forceSelection="true"
                            maxlength="6"
                            cache="true"
                            queryDelay="100"
                            value="#{searchController.locality}"
                            completeMethod="#{searchController.completeLocality}">
            </p:autoComplete>
            <p:watermark for="localityDD"
                         value="Search Locality"
                         id="localityWatermark" />
        </div>

        <div class="serbox subsel mydropbox">
            <p:calendar required="false"
                        requiredMessage="Date required"
                        id="date"
                        value="#{searchController.date}"
                        pattern="MM/dd/yyyy">
                <p:watermark for="date" value="Search Date" id="dateWatermark" />
            </p:calendar>
            <p:message for="date" />
        </div>

        <div class="serbox hserbtn">
            <p:commandLink id="searchBtn"
                           update="validate_home"
                           action="#{searchController.simpleSearch}">
                <p:graphicImage value="images/search_home.png" alt="" title="" />
            </p:commandLink>
        </div>
    </p:panel>
</h:form>
```

Comment: Do you want the autoComplete textbox to be blank. In that case clear the binding reference in managed bean when you do the action.

Comment: Here is my bean class method.                                                                   private void clearSearchForm() {  
  this.testName = "";
  this.city = "";
  this.locality = "";
  this.zip = "";
  this.date = null;
 }                                                                                                                                                       But here when i click on search button i just call this method. then autoComplete values are clear. it is ok.. after select one autoComplete value then refresh values should clear.. It is not happening.

Comment: What do you mean by refresh here and what is the scope of the managed bean.  Binding still persists and hence the problem. While clicking on back, is it not going to the previous page?

Comment: That means.. After i clicked on search button getting displayed search results.. then clicked on back button on browser go to the previous page.. data should be clear.. Here previous selected values are filling...

Comment: The attribute `update` is not defined in the component `<p:autoComplete>`.

Comment: Is your managed bean view scoped?. I hope so as per the behaviour you are telling.

Comment: Yes it is view Scope.. can any one help me..is there any chance clear data..